# How to vote on comments?

Tags: support, comments, privileges, comment-votes

I believe that the numbers at the beginning of a comment is the number of votes on it.

I searched and tried to find it, but I couldn't: how can I vote on a comment? Is there a reputation limit?

Comment: Yes: you need a reputation of 15 or greater to vote on comments, same as for voting on questions and answers. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yep, 15 rep is required. After you reach 15 rep (which, believe me, is not really hard) on hovering a comment you'll see an arrow:

> [image]

Click it.

> [image]

Yay. Comment upvoted.

Comment: Thanks for the image, i got confused because eventhought i cannot vote there is arrows for answers, but nothing related to comments.

Answer (score 8):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

I do not see the badge `Informed` in your status, which suggests you chose *not* to take the introductory [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) after signing up. One of its (many) hints for beginners is

> As you earn reputation, you'll unlock new privileges like the ability to vote, comment, and even edit other people's posts.

and on the specific topic of commenting:

> You can always comment on your own questions and answers. Once you earn 50 reputation, you can comment on anybody's post.

The [Help Center > Privileges > comment everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) contains a description of commenting, but the upvote number itself is mentioned in [Help Center > Privileges > Vote Up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up/) and is **15**, as others helpfully pointed out.

"I searched, tried to find but i couldn't find":
For help on using SO's own infrastructure, visit the Help Center (a suitable link is included in aforementioned Tour), which has a Search feature of its own:

https://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: Bolding 50 rep requirement to comment doesn't make any sense...

Comment: @nicael: (...) By Jove, you are right! That is for *commenting*, not *voting on comments*. So where is the limit for comment-voting described? (NM, brain freeze -- just found it.)